# Hello, please tell me how to send ArrayList to another activity

Tags: android, arraylist

I tried all the possible options that I just found.
I can’t send ArrayList to another activity via the Parcelable interface.
To implement a media player
String format information it sends.

I would be very grateful, maybe there are some other options. This is the first time I'm asking a question here

Here is my activity that I use to send, the code is still very raw

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private ImageView btn_Play;
    private ImageView btn_Next;
    private ImageView btn_Pre;
    private TextView setCurrentDuration, setTotalDuration;

    private ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
    SoundAdapter adapter = new SoundAdapter();

    public Handler handler = new Handler();
    AudioEffect audioEffect;

    private int currentPosition = 0;

    private SoundInfo soundInfo = new SoundInfo(this);
    SoundEffects soundEffects;
    boolean mediaPauseStat = false;
    Context context;
    PageFragmentOne pageFragmentOne;
    //public MainActivity(PageFragmentOne pageFragmentOne) {
    //    this.pageFragmentOne = pageFragmentOne;
    //}

    MediaManager mediaManager = new MediaManager(this, adapter, audioList);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Старт сервиса


        //Intent i = new Intent(this, MediaPlaybackService.class);
        //i.putExtra("play", "письмо от главного активити");
        //startService(i);

        //mediaManager.LoadSounds();
        /**
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
**/

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




        setCurrentDuration = findViewById(R.id.current_Duration);
        setTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.total_Duration);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


        RecyclerView list = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        // Оформление отображения адаптера
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_item_divider, null));
        list.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        soundInfo.setMassive(audioList);



        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SoundAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, final SoundInfo obj, final int position, final ImageView onNext) {
                final SoundInfo path = audioList.get(position);
                String audioPath = obj.getData();
                prepareMedia(position);

                // Задаем текующию позицию трека
                currentPosition = position;

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mediaPlayer.start();

                        // Всегда должен быть после старта плеера, что бы не вылазило 238
                        updateProgressBar();
                        //seekBar.setProgress(0);
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                        btn_Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                });

                // Перемотка аудио
                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        // Слишком часто обновляет
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            soundInfo.setMediaPauseStat(false);
                            soundInfo.setMediaRewind(false);
                            mediaPlayer.pause();

                            seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            soundInfo.setMediaPauseStat(true);
                            //soundInfo.setMediaRewind(true);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Кнопка проигрывания и паузы
                btn_Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            onPlay();
                        } else {
                            onPaused();

                        }
                    }
                });

                // Следующий трек
                btn_Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        onNext();
                    }
                });

                // Предыдущий трек
                btn_Pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        onPre();
                    }
                });
            }
        });



        init();
    }



    private MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("YourAction");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        myReceiver = null;
    }

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           // String yourValue = b.getString("ser");

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        }
    }


    public void onMainMediaPlayList(View view) {

        final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMediaPlayList.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("MEDIA_MASSIVE", audioList);
        intent2.putExtras(bundle);


        startActivity(intent2);



        //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MediaPlaybackService.class);
        //startService(i);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    }

    public void init() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Разрешение не предоставляется
            // Должны ли мы показать объяснение?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Показать объяснение пользователю * асинхронно* -- не блокировать
                // этот поток ждет ответа пользователя! После пользователя
                // увидев объяснение, попробуйте еще раз запросить разрешение.
            } else {
                // Никаких объяснений не требуется; запросить разрешение
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                        101);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS является
                // app-определенная константа int. Метод обратного вызова получает
                // результат запроса.
            }
        } else {
            // Разрешение уже предоставлено
            //loadSounds();
            mediaManager.LoadSounds();
        }

        //bPlayPause = findViewById(R.id.bPlayPause);
        //lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPlayList);
        btn_Play = findViewById(R.id.btn_Play);
        btn_Next = findViewById(R.id.btn_Next);
        btn_Pre = findViewById(R.id.btn_Pre);
    }
```

Here is my SoundInfo

```
public class SoundInfo implements Parcelable {
    private String data, artist, title;

    private Context context;
    private String pathData;

    public SoundInfo(MainActivity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SoundInfo() {
    }

    public SoundInfo(MainMediaPlayList context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    public SoundInfo(MediaPlaybackService mediaPlaybackService, String star) {
        this.context = mediaPlaybackService;
        this.star = star;
    }


    protected SoundInfo(Parcel in) {
        data = in.readString();
        artist = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
        pathData = in.readString();
        mediaPauseStat = in.readByte() != 0;
        ismediaRewind = in.readByte() != 0;
        audioList = in.createTypedArrayList(SoundInfo.CREATOR);
        star = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<SoundInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<SoundInfo>() {
        @Override
        public SoundInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SoundInfo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SoundInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SoundInfo[size];
        }
    };

    public void SoundInfo(String data, String artist, String title) {
        this.data = data;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public SoundInfo(String data, String artist, String title) {
        this.data = data;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public void setData(String artist) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setpathData(String pathData) {
        this.pathData = pathData;
    }

    public String getpathData() {
        return pathData;
    }

    // Запись в память для отображения времени


    boolean mediaPauseStat = true;
    boolean ismediaRewind = true;

    public void setMediaPauseStat(boolean mediaPauseStat) {
        this.mediaPauseStat = mediaPauseStat;
    }

    public boolean getMediaPauseStat() {
        return mediaPauseStat;
    }


    public void setMediaRewind(boolean isMediaRewind) {
        this.ismediaRewind = ismediaRewind;
    }

    public boolean getMediaRewind() {
        return ismediaRewind;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Массив
    private ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = new ArrayList<SoundInfo>();

    public ArrayList<SoundInfo> getMassive() {
        return audioList;
    }
    public void setMassive(ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList) {
        this.audioList = audioList;
    }

    private String star;
    public String getStar() {
        return star;
    }
    public void setStar(String star) {
        this.star = star;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(data);
        dest.writeString(artist);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(pathData);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (mediaPauseStat ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeByte((byte) (ismediaRewind ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeTypedList(audioList);
        dest.writeString(star);
    }
}
```

Here is my adater which I use

```
public class SoundAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = new ArrayList<SoundInfo>();
    Context context;

    //private String[] items;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public void setItems(Context context, ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.audioList = audioList;
        //audioList.addAll(items);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_audio, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bind(audioList.get(position));

        holder.clickFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final SoundInfo path = audioList.get(position);
                onItemClickListener.onClick(view, path, position, holder.onNext);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return audioList == null ? 0 : audioList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView data, title, artist;
        private ImageView onNext;
        private View clickFile;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSoundTitle);
            artist = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSoundArtist);
            clickFile = view.findViewById(R.id.clickFile);
            //data = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            //onNext = view.findViewById(R.id.imageNext);
        }
        public void bind(SoundInfo soundInfo) {
            title.setText(soundInfo.getTitle());
            artist.setText(soundInfo.getArtist());
            //clickFile.setText(soundInfo.getData());
        }
    }

    // Передача данных в основной активити
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, SoundInfo obj, int position, ImageView onNext);
    }
}
```

Here is the second activity that an ArrayList gets.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("MEDIA_MASSIVE");

        adapter.setItems(MainMediaPlayList.this, audioList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        // загрузка адаптера
        RecyclerView list = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainMediaPlayList.this));
```

When you open a new activity, the application crashes
does not display any errors in the log, the problem is as I understand that intent can not find
audioList as it seems to me
If I remove the method everything loads

```
public void onMainMediaPlayList(View view) {

        final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMediaPlayList.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("MEDIA_MASSIVE", audioList);
        intent2.putExtras(bundle);


        startActivity(intent2);
```

Here I took off the launch log, it may somehow help

```
2020-03-08 18:09:43.406 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication W/r.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-03-08 18:09:43.406 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication W/r.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-03-08 18:09:43.431 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication I/OverScrollerOptimization: start init SmartSlideOverScroller and get the overscroller config
2020-03-08 18:09:43.431 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication I/OverScrollerOptimization: get the overscroller config
2020-03-08 18:09:43.466 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication D/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in.
2020-03-08 18:09:43.466 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication I/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory.
2020-03-08 18:09:43.506 15730-15730/com.shimmer.myapplication D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{e3185e4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@837d3d7 {com.shimmer.myapplication/com.shimmer.myapplication.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@837d3d7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, You can send an ArrayList like this.

I recommend you sending Class instead of sending an Arraylist.

So, just create a class like AudiolistHolder and put your ArrayList inside this class and don't forget to implement Parcelable interface for this class, too, and send this class between activities this should solve your problem. I always use this way.

EDIT:

You can use this to send your data

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainMediaPlayList.class);
MassiveAudioList m = new MassiveAudioList(audioList);
intent2.putExtra("MEDIA_MASSIVE”, m);
startActivity(intent2);
```

and you can use this in your second activity to retrieve data

```
MassiveAudioList massiveAudio=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MEDIA_MASSIVE");

ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = massiveAudio.getMassiveAudioList();
```

Comment: I’m trying to do as you said, but don’t know if it’s right or not, as I’m still new to this field.         ```  final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMediaPlayList.class);
        
        massiveAudioList = new MassiveAudioList(this);

        MassiveAudioList m = new MassiveAudioList(audioList);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("MEDIA_MASSIVE", m);
        intent2.putExtras(bundle);


        startActivity(intent2); ```

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can look at it @РоманЛлл

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this with arraylist
I think it can be,
In MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> audioList= new ArrayList<>();
audioList.add("ChipThrills");
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
i.putExtra("Musickey", audioList);
startActivity(i);
```

In SecondActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> audioList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Musickey");
```

Comment: I have not tried such a format, then I will have to transfer all the mediaManager code to the class that fills the audioList.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing to you here because I did not understand how to add code to the comment

And how do I extract data by adding it to an array. If of course I did the right thing, I'm new to this field. Thanks.

```
public class MassiveAudioList implements  Parcelable {

    private ArrayList<SoundInfo> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public MassiveAudioList(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MassiveAudioList(ArrayList audioList) {
        this.audioList = audioList;
    }

    protected MassiveAudioList(Parcel in) {
        audioList = in.createTypedArrayList(SoundInfo.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<MassiveAudioList> CREATOR = new Creator<MassiveAudioList>() {
        @Override
        public MassiveAudioList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MassiveAudioList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MassiveAudioList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MassiveAudioList[size];
        }
    };

    public ArrayList<SoundInfo> getMassiveAudioList() {
        return audioList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeTypedList(audioList);
    }
}
```

```
 public void onMainMediaPlayList(View view) {
        Log.d("TAG", "soundinfo" + soundInfo.getData());
        final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMediaPlayList.class);

        massiveAudioList = new MassiveAudioList(this);

        MassiveAudioList m = new MassiveAudioList(audioList);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("MEDIA_MASSIVE", m);
        intent2.putExtras(bundle);


        startActivity(intent2);

    }
```